# Install GitLab on Apache as subdirectory

Tags: 18.04, apache2, gitlab

I have an existing Ubuntu LAMP server already setup and working with my domain. I want to install GitLab on my Apache installation, and I want to be able to access it like a subdirectory (eg. example.com/gitlab).

Most of the tutorials are for Ubuntu 16.04, and they don't seem to work for 18.04. I've tried a bunch of tutorials but I can never get GitLab to work at all running on Apache.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First, install GitLab according to its installation instructions, but make sure to [install it under a relative URL](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/relative_url.html). Note that GitLab recommends installation at a root URL, but that would prevent it from running within the "URL space" of your existing web server.

Once you have your GitLab instance up and running, say on http://internal.domain:1234/gitlab, you make your Apache proxy it. In the Apache configuration add a `Location` section like this:

```
<Location /gitlab>
    ProxyPass http://internal.domain:1234/gitlab
    ProxyPassReverse http://internal.domain:1234/gitlab
</Location>
```

Since your Apache will terminate the https connection, if the GitLab is on http, you'll need to tell GitLab this:

```
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Ssl on
```

Note that you'll also need to port forward `ssh` traffic from your public IP to the GitLab server. Otherwise `git clone 'git@...'` cannot work and you're limited to `git clone https://...`.